# How to programmatically trigger validation on a field in 'react-hook-form'?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I try to do it like so, but it does nothing...

```
import {useForm, FormContext} from 'react-hook-form';

const formMethods = useForm({mode: 'onSubmit'});
const {triggerValidation} = formMethods;
triggerValidation('myFieldName');

return (
    <FormContext {...formMethods}>
        //here are my form fields, one of which has the key of 'myFieldName'
    </FormContext>
);
```

Comment: When do you want to trigger the validation?

Comment: @TheTisiboth I want to trigger it within the `onChange` of one input (actually `onChange` of a wrapper - `Controller`), to enforce the validation of another input. But regardless, it doesn't work even within the `useEffect`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you've to use `trigger` method: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger

Comment: hmm this didn't work for me - `await trigger()` resolves to true and `formState.isValid` is true before and after calling it, even when one of the fields contains an invalid value